# operand size for "out"

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I'm using the GAS assembler.
I'm trying to write to the I/O port 0x20, I do it like this:

```
outb $0x20, $0x20
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for out
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no encoding for `out imm, imm` in the x86 instruction set manual. The only encodings are for `out imm8, [e]a[x/l]`, and `out dx, [e]a[x/l]`, each writing the value from the `[e]a[x/l]` register.

Answer (score 2):

See https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html.

You can't have two immediates for operands for `out`. This has nothing to do with the operand size or suffix of `out`.

Comment: Not in this instruction, at least (`enter` certainly has).